# Allow AWS Private EC2 HTTP and HTTPS to Public

Tags: amazon-web-services

Apologies for the question as I'm still learning AWS, currently I am exploring using a Private EC2 running Windows Server IIS to connect to a Database via Site-to-site VPN/VPC to a on-premise DC, aside from the Database connection/port, I'll allow access to RDP via the VPN.

However I wanted users to access the IIS HTTP and HTTPS from the public. what are steps or requirements to it, I've read that it requires a ELB? Appreciate your feedback and hopefully point me to the right direction or resources. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. You started by talking about a Windows server connecting to a database, but then changed to talking about accessing the server itself via HTTP/S. And you mention RDP as well. Could you please clarify what is your _specific_ question? Also let us know what you have tried and what problem(s) you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi John,

so the Windows server will be a Web server, hence the IIS service, but it needs to connect to a Database but the Database is hosted in an onprem Datacenter, hence the need to do S2S IPSec between Windows server EC2 to the Database. RDP is allowed as I need to manage the Webserver from the Onprem Datacenter via the S2S IPSec.

then finally, the Windows server/Web server itself needs to be accessible on the internet via HTTP/S.

Comment: What i've did so far, created a Private VPC, and S2S to my onprem server, where the EC2 and DB is already reaching through it and can access and manage the EC2 via RDP.

Since the EC2 and VPC is private. how can I allow the EC2 then to the public to access it since its also a webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just running a single web server, you could put it in a **public subnet** of the VPC. This will make it accessible from the Internet and it would also be able to communicate with the database via the connection you have put in place.

Be sure to configure the **security group** on the web server so that it only opens HTTP/S (ports 80, 443) from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) and (if desired) RDP only from your personal IP address. That will keep it perfectly secure without needing to place it into a private subnet.

If you had multiple web servers, then a **Load Balancer** would be appropriate, but that does not seem to be necessary for your system.

By the way, it is not a great idea to separate an application from its database due to **latency**. Your app might suffer because it is remote from the database. Hopefully the latency is low enough for your application to work adequately.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll consider these. yes the goal was to setup multiple webserver which is why I bump into the ELB topic.

Comment: Hi John, I was able to achieve that the private subnet are behind a ALB and the servers(IIS) are now accessible in the internet and have pointed the DNS name to my DNS hosting and Cloudflare as CNAME. I'm curious, I only wanted Load balancing but since I have a Cloudflare WAF and I would want to offloading SSL using that instead of the AWS ALB. what would be the approach in the AWS ALB where I can allow SSL/HTTPS without importing SSL to it(given that as mentioned I'll SSL offload on Cloudflare)? 

What I've tried so far is allow on the ALB-Security group port 443, but to no avail.

Comment: Please create a new question. Somebody should be able to assist.